# How to create virtual host in Xampp windows 10

Tags: windows, xampp, host

I want to setup virtual host for my local project.

I added this code into `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/bab/"
    ServerName bab.local
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/bab/">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I added this code into `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`file.

```
127.0.0.1       bab.local
```

please help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your settings like below :- need to define {projectName}

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/bab/{projectName}"
    ServerName bab.local
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/bab/">

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have added `D:/xampp/htdocs/pos` in my `Document` and `Directory` as well. As my project is under `pos` folder

Comment: also getting 404 error

Comment: Just use the "D:/xampp/htdocs/pos/{projectName}" for both Document and Directory.
Restart the Server and check.